# I accidentally uninstalled the Python binaries that came bundled with Fedora, now yum and dnf both aren't working

Tags: python, fedora

So, I know I'm pretty stupid, and I did something stupid today.
Whilst trying to find out why in the world there was a disparity between my manual-installed Python 3.9 installation and the terminal, and I found out the cause. The pre-bundled Python binaries were the cause, me being me, I deleted them without giving a second thought, now, well, haha, I'm stuck pretty much. Both yum and dnf have stopped working and I realized that they both ran on that binary... any help would be appreciated. Very much stuck because I'm a Fedora novice. Thanks!

dnf:

```
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/dnf: No such file or directory
```

yum/yum-deprecated:

```
sudo: yum-deprecated: command not found
bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Do you have anything important on this system? If not, I would say the easiest thing you can do here is a reinstall of Fedora and try not to make the same mistake again. Saying this to be helpful quickly rather than going through looking for a really in-depth technical answer. Sorry you have to deal with this, but mistakes are how we learn :)

Comment: StackOverflow is better suited for pure programming questions. You will probably be able to get better help on https://serverfault.com/.

Comment: @Harlin, the question says dnf does not work either so that answer wont work in this senario.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Harlin! I kinda use that as my main OS, and have no backup except for my USB, which is kinda broken and it's tedious to reinstall it because it kinda stops working mid-installation. Installing simply isn't worth it because I have a ton of important stuff on here, I kinda use that as my main and I want to get yum and dnf both working without a reinstall, that'd be great if I can. Again, thank you! :D

Comment: My bad, sorry, Locke. I found a few people asking that here, and this place is mostly active, so I tried it here. Apologies.

Comment: Does `rpm` still work?  If so, you could look in `/var/log/dnf.log` and see which packages were removed.  Then you could find/download the RPMs from https://koji.fedoraproject.org/ and reinstall those packages with `rpm`.  If successful, and `dnf` is working normally,  I would also reinstall all those packages with `dnf`.  If you directly deleted the binaries, you could extract them from the RPMs and put them back (if you remember what you did).  Are all your commands in `bash` `history`?

Comment: Yes, it does still work.

Comment: I remember what I did.
sudo su and then removed Python2.7 or something.

Comment: "bash: /var/log/dnf.log: Permission denied" this shows up when I try to access "/var/log/dnf.log" even after getting root privileges.

Comment: Exactly how did you remove/delete/uninstall? What commands did you use? Is there a `bash` history of your commands? What version of Fedora are you using? What does `sudo ls -l /var/log/*dnf*` show? It's OK to edit your original question to show more information.

Comment: Wait. Please bear with me. I executed this command on December 8.

Comment: -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  68300 Dec  8 19:21 /var/log/dnf.librepo.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 257273 Dec  8 19:21 /var/log/dnf.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   7956 Dec  8 19:21 /var/log/dnf.rpm.log

Comment: "I deleted them" ... how? ... with `sudo rm a_bunch_of_file_names`?  ... with `dnf remove a_bunch_of_packages`? ... with a GUI file manager?

Comment: With just ```sudo rm python2```

Comment: And do you have a full list of the full paths that you deleted?  BTW, if you start a comment with @rickhg12hs I should get a notification.  I only occasionally check Q/As that I have commented on.

Comment: Assuming `python2` was in `/usr/bin/`, you could `rpm -q -f /usr/bin/python2`.  This will tell you the RPM where it came from.  Next you could go to koji.fedoraproject.org, find the RPM and `rpm -i --replacepkgs the_correct_package.rpm`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a different method of re-installing Python 3.9? For example, download the source and install following [instructions from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html):

```
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.9/Python-3.9.9.tgz
$ tar -xvf Python-3.9.9.tgz
$ cd Python-3.9.9.tgz
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

Comment: I'll try it, also, do I need to reboot in order to apply the changes? Because yum and  dnf still aren't working.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work.